How can I list all attributes of the 'Child' node (in this case 'name' and 'id' and get their values in a loop to be captured individually?

<Children name='Children'>

  <child name='Child_2' id='2'>child2_Parent_1</child>

  <child name='Child_4' id='4'>child4_Parent_1</child>

  <child name='Child_1' id='3'>child1_Parent_1</child>

  <child name='Child_3' id='1'>child3_Parent_1</child>

</Children>

<Children name='Children'>

  <child name='Child_1' id='8'>child1_parent2</child>

  <child name='Child_2' id='7'>child2_parent2</child>

  <child name='Child_4' id='6'>child4_parent2</child>

  <child name='Child_3' id='5'>child3_parent2</child>

</Children>

All other posts I seen had shown to get values for specific named node attribute(s). I want to dynamically get the attribute names (which I may not know) for a node and get the values. Any help would be appreciated.

It's easy enough to get all the attributes using something like //Children/child/@*. But after that, the question is what do you want to do with them?

It really depends on the XML, in this case to get all the child nodes you can use the XPath //child then for the attributes you can get them from .Attributes assuming you don't know them ahead of time, so for example, if you want to construct an object dynamically from this sample XML:
$xml = [xml] @'
<Children name='Children'>
  <child name='Child_2' id='2'>child2_Parent_1</child>
  <child name='Child_4' id='4'>child4_Parent_1</child>
  <child name='Child_1' id='3'>child1_Parent_1</child>
  <child name='Child_3' id='1'>child3_Parent_1</child>
</Children>
'@

You can approach it like:
$xml.SelectNodes('//child') | ForEach-Object {
    $obj = [ordered]@{}
    foreach ($attribute in $_.Attributes) {
        $obj[$attribute.Name] = $attribute.Value
    }
    $obj['InnerText'] = $_.InnerText
    [pscustomobject] $obj
}

Which results in:
name    id InnerText
----    -- ---------
Child_2 2  child2_Parent_1
Child_4 4  child4_Parent_1
Child_1 3  child1_Parent_1
Child_3 1  child3_Parent_1

